# Boolean Logic Simplification: (A+B)'(A'+B')'=?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to simplify the following Boolean expression :
(A+B)'(A'+B')'=? 
but I am really new in boolean algebra, so please can anyone explain to me how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By De Morgan, this is $A'B'AB$, hence $false$.